# PCL "profile 111" - how to install on TFS build server?

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild, portable-class-library

I have a VS2013 solution containing a PCL project that targets .Net 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1. It builds on my dev PC but fails on the build server (TFS 2012):-

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (983): The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111" were not found. To
>   resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework
>   version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for
>   which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that
>   assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and
>   will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly
>   may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

What must I install to get "profile 111" on the build server? Or could I just copy the profile folder from my dev PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a separate download to include the reference assemblies,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727

Once installed, you get all the profiles needed. Further information can be found from Xamarin,

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have VS 2013 installed on your build server?  If not I suggest installing it.

Answer (score 1):

The "profile 111" seems available only with VS2013 Update 3... http://lastexitcode.com/projects/NuGet/PortableProfiles/

That's weird for a build server.. but it seems to be the only way until that asp.net 5 will be really usable for prod.